# what this syntax in libev C language?

Tags: c, libev

While reading the doc in [libev](http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/libev/ev.pod) I find some C code of which the syntax is quite weird.

```
static void
stdin_cb (EV_P_ ev_io *w, int revents)
{
     puts ("stdin ready");
     // for one-shot events, one must manually stop the watcher
     // with its corresponding stop function.
     ev_io_stop (EV_A_ w);

     // this causes all nested ev_run's to stop iterating
     ev_break (EV_A_ EVBREAK_ALL);
}
```

I'm not sure what the `EV_P_` is here, could anyone help explain it to me?

I have tried to google the syntax of method signature in C but no good matches.

Comment: See the **Macro magic** section of the linked documentation.

Comment: Please confirm that the syntax you are asking about is indeed `**EV_P_**` (i.e. including the two leading and trailing `**`, which really takes some explaining. Or is it an ill-placed attempt to use markdown inside your code? Better show the code with the syntax as you want to discuss it. Or, to put it differently: Does the code example in  your post really look like you want it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [ev.h](https://github.com/enki/libev/blob/master/ev.h#L173):

```
#if EV_MULTIPLICITY
struct ev_loop;
# define EV_P  struct ev_loop *loop /* a loop as sole parameter in a declaration */
# define EV_P_ EV_P,                /* a loop as first of multiple parameters */
...
#else
# define EV_P void
# define EV_P_
...
#endif
```

Therefore the line

```
stdin_cb (EV_P_ ev_io *w, int revents)
```

expands to

```
stdin_cb (struct ev_loop *loop, ev_io *w, int revents)
```

or

```
stdin_cb (ev_io *w, int revents)
```

depending on the value of `EV_MULTIPLICITY`

As pointed out by @Shawn, there is a [Macro magic section](http://pod.tst.eu/http://cvs.schmorp.de/libev/ev.pod#MACRO_MAGIC) that explains it:

> EV_P, EV_P_
>
> ```
> This provides the loop parameter for functions, if one is required ("ev loop parameter"). The EV_P form is used when this is the sole parameter, EV_P_ is used when other parameters are following. Example:
>
>    // this is how ev_unref is being declared
>    static void ev_unref (EV_P);
>
>    // this is how you can declare your typical callback
>    static void cb (EV_P_ ev_timer *w, int revents)
>
> It declares a parameter loop of type struct ev_loop *, quite suitable for use with EV_A.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

`EV_P_` is a macro which means "an ev loop as a parameter, plus a comma".

`EV_A_` is a macro which means "an ev loop as an argument, plus a comma".

They are [defined](https://github.com/enki/libev/blob/master/ev.h) as

```c
#define EV_P  struct ev_loop *loop  /* a loop as sole parameter in a declaration */
#define EV_P_ EV_P,                 /* a loop as first of multiple parameters */
#define EV_A  loop                  /* a loop as sole argument to a function call */
#define EV_A_ EV_A,                 /* a loop as first of multiple arguments */
```

or as

```c
# define EV_P void
# define EV_P_
# define EV_A
# define EV_A_
```

(Some whitespace was removed so it would fit better.)

This means

```c
static void stdin_cb( EV_P_ ev_io *w, int revents ) {
     puts( "stdin ready" );
     ev_io_stop( EV_A_ w );
     ev_break( EV_A_ EVBREAK_ALL );
}
```

is equivalent to

```c
static void stdin_cb( struct ev_loop *loop, ev_io *w, int revents ) {
     puts( "stdin ready" );
     ev_io_stop( loop, w );
     ev_break( loop, EVBREAK_ALL );
}
```

or

```c
static void stdin_cb( ev_io *w, int revents ) {
     puts( "stdin ready" );
     ev_io_stop( w );
     ev_break( EVBREAK_ALL );
}
```

Which set of `#define` directives is used is configurable.

If `EV_MULTIPLICITY` is set and nonzero, the first set is used. The first set allows multiple ev loops to be used in the same program. (Perhaps in different threads.)

If `EV_MULTIPLICITY` is unset or zero, the second set is used. The second is more efficient since it uses global variables instead of passing a structure to every ev-related function. But the program can only have one event loop.